# Problem with multiple inputs inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, input, angular8, emoji, two-way-binding

I'm using

- Angular 8
- @ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart

In the application below you can create a new post and leave a comment for each post.
[image]

I just implement this library for emojis and right now I'm using two-way binding and the comments are in *ngFor which causes a problem since the comment is written in all forms at once, however, if I don’t use two-way binding, I can’t display the emoji because it’s added with a function. Any advice how do I approach this?

```
                <div class="input-group">
                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o emoji-picker-icon mr-1" (click)="toggleEmojiPickerForComment($event)"></i>
                    <input class="form-control" #textComment placeholder="share your thoughts"
                        type="text">
                </div>
 <emoji-mart class="emoji-mart" set="emojione" (emojiSelect)="addEmoji($event)" *ngIf="showEmojiPicker" title="Pick your emoji…"></emoji-mart>
```